Regression line not completely show on whole Data in Vegalite
I tried to create a chart in vegalite having trendline(regression in vegalite) on the line (value) data , regression line is create but not complete visible on whole data ( on last few).
I not getting why this is happening in my chart.

regression line (black) not till the end
Editor link

You're mixing two different x axes. Try this:

{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"id": 1, "Period": "01-Jan-21-31-Jan-21", "value": "96.98"},
      {"id": 2, "Period": "11-Jan-21-07-Feb-21", "value": "97.01"},
      {"id": 3, "Period": "18-Jan-21-14-Feb-21", "value": "96.85"},
      {"id": 4, "Period": "25-Jan-21-21-Feb-21", "value": "96.6"},
      {"id": 5, "Period": "01-Feb-21-28-Feb-21", "value": "95.82"},
      {"id": 6, "Period": "08-Feb-21-07-Mar-21", "value": "95.49"},
      {"id": 7, "Period": "15-Feb-21-14-Mar-21", "value": "95.44"},
      {"id": 8, "Period": "22-Feb-21-21-Mar-21", "value": "95.34"},
      {"id": 9, "Period": "01-Mar-21-31-Mar-21", "value": "95.39"},
      {"id": 10, "Period": "08-Mar-21-04-Apr-21", "value": "95.89"},
      {"id": 11, "Period": "15-Mar-21-11-Apr-21", "value": "95.78"},
      {"id": 12, "Period": "22-Mar-21-18-Apr-21", "value": "95.94"},
      {"id": 13, "Period": "01-Apr-21-25-Apr-21", "value": "95.99"},
      {"id": 14, "Period": "05-Apr-21-30-Apr-21", "value": "95.8"},
      {"id": 15, "Period": "12-Apr-21-09-May-21", "value": "95.58"},
      {"id": 16, "Period": "19-Apr-21-16-May-21", "value": "95.17"},
      {"id": 17, "Period": "26-Apr-21-23-May-21", "value": "95.18"},
      {"id": 18, "Period": "01-May-21-31-May-21", "value": "95.07"},
      {"id": 19, "Period": "10-May-21-06-Jun-21", "value": "95.26"},
      {"id": 20, "Period": "17-May-21-13-Jun-21", "value": "95.33"},
      {"id": 21, "Period": "24-May-21-20-Jun-21", "value": "95.3"},
      {"id": 22, "Period": "01-Jun-21-30-Jun-21", "value": "95.4"},
      {"id": 23, "Period": "07-Jun-21-04-Jul-21", "value": "95.16"},
      {"id": 24, "Period": "14-Jun-21-11-Jul-21", "value": "95.73"},
      {"id": 25, "Period": "21-Jun-21-18-Jul-21", "value": "95.97"},
      {"id": 26, "Period": "01-Jul-21-25-Jul-21", "value": "95.4"},
      {"id": 27, "Period": "05-Jul-21-31-Jul-21", "value": "95.4"},
      {"id": 28, "Period": "12-Jul-21-08-Aug-21", "value": "94.86"},
      {"id": 29, "Period": "19-Jul-21-15-Aug-21", "value": "94.43"},
      {"id": 30, "Period": "26-Jul-21-22-Aug-21", "value": "95.43"},
      {"id": 31, "Period": "01-Aug-21-31-Aug-21", "value": "95.97"},
      {"id": 32, "Period": "09-Aug-21-05-Sep-21", "value": "96.6"},
      {"id": 33, "Period": "16-Aug-21-12-Sep-21", "value": "97.02"},
      {"id": 34, "Period": "23-Aug-21-19-Sep-21", "value": "96.68"},
      {"id": 35, "Period": "01-Sep-21-26-Sep-21", "value": "97.32"},
      {"id": 36, "Period": "06-Sep-21-30-Sep-21", "value": "97.05"},
      {"id": 37, "Period": "13-Sep-21-10-Oct-21", "value": "96.78"},
      {"id": 38, "Period": "20-Sep-21-17-Oct-21", "value": "96.77"},
      {"id": 39, "Period": "27-Sep-21-24-Oct-21", "value": "96.3"},
      {"id": 40, "Period": "01-Oct-21-31-Oct-21", "value": "96.74"},
      {"id": 41, "Period": "11-Oct-21-07-Nov-21", "value": "96.79"},
      {"id": 42, "Period": "18-Oct-21-14-Nov-21", "value": "97.06"},
      {"id": 43, "Period": "25-Oct-21-21-Nov-21", "value": "96.44"},
      {"id": 44, "Period": "01-Nov-21-30-Nov-21", "value": "96.0"},
      {"id": 45, "Period": "08-Nov-21-05-Dec-21", "value": "96.12"},
      {"id": 46, "Period": "15-Nov-21-12-Dec-21", "value": "96.23"},
      {"id": 47, "Period": "22-Nov-21-19-Dec-21", "value": "96.99"},
      {"id": 48, "Period": "01-Dec-21-26-Dec-21", "value": "97.42"},
      {"id": 49, "Period": "06-Dec-21-31-Dec-21", "value": "97.58"},
      {"id": 50, "Period": "13-Dec-21-09-Jan-22", "value": "97.08"},
      {"id": 51, "Period": "20-Dec-21-16-Jan-22", "value": "96.72"},
      {"id": 52, "Period": "27-Dec-21-23-Jan-22", "value": "96.04"},
      {"id": 53, "Period": "01-Jan-22-31-Jan-22", "value": "95.62"},
      {"id": 54, "Period": "10-Jan-22-06-Feb-22", "value": "95.72"},
      {"id": 55, "Period": "17-Jan-22-13-Feb-22", "value": "95.22"},
      {"id": 56, "Period": "24-Jan-22-20-Feb-22", "value": "95.25"},
      {"id": 57, "Period": "01-Feb-22-28-Feb-22", "value": "95.35"},
      {"id": 58, "Period": "07-Feb-22-06-Mar-22", "value": "95.42"},
      {"id": 59, "Period": "14-Feb-22-13-Mar-22", "value": "96.03"},
      {"id": 60, "Period": "21-Feb-22-20-Mar-22", "value": "96.38"},
      {"id": 61, "Period": "01-Mar-22-27-Mar-22", "value": "96.68"},
      {"id": 62, "Period": "07-Mar-22-31-Mar-22", "value": "96.67"},
      {"id": 63, "Period": "14-Mar-22-10-Apr-22", "value": "96.8"},
      {"id": 64, "Period": "21-Mar-22-17-Apr-22", "value": "96.87"},
      {"id": 65, "Period": "28-Mar-22-24-Apr-22", "value": "97.1"},
      {"id": 66, "Period": "01-Apr-22-30-Apr-22", "value": "96.94"},
      {"id": 67, "Period": "11-Apr-22-08-May-22", "value": "96.36"},
      {"id": 68, "Period": "18-Apr-22-15-May-22", "value": "96.26"},
      {"id": 69, "Period": "25-Apr-22-22-May-22", "value": "96.09"},
      {"id": 70, "Period": "01-May-22-31-May-22", "value": "96.18"},
      {"id": 71, "Period": "09-May-22-05-Jun-22", "value": "96.49"},
      {"id": 72, "Period": "16-May-22-12-Jun-22", "value": "96.34"},
      {"id": 73, "Period": "23-May-22-19-Jun-22", "value": "96.52"},
      {"id": 74, "Period": "01-Jun-22-26-Jun-22", "value": "96.49"},
      {"id": 75, "Period": "06-Jun-22-30-Jun-22", "value": "96.68"},
      {"id": 76, "Period": "13-Jun-22-10-Jul-22", "value": "96.87"},
      {"id": 77, "Period": "20-Jun-22-17-Jul-22", "value": "96.28"},
      {"id": 78, "Period": "27-Jun-22-24-Jul-22", "value": "96.45"},
      {"id": 79, "Period": "01-Jul-22-31-Jul-22", "value": "95.96"},
      {"id": 80, "Period": "11-Jul-22-07-Aug-22", "value": "95.04"},
      {"id": 81, "Period": "18-Jul-22-14-Aug-22", "value": "94.29"},
      {"id": 82, "Period": "25-Jul-22-21-Aug-22", "value": "93.8"},
      {"id": 83, "Period": "01-Aug-22-31-Aug-22", "value": "93.85"},
      {"id": 84, "Period": "08-Aug-22-04-Sep-22", "value": "94.15"},
      {"id": 85, "Period": "15-Aug-22-11-Sep-22", "value": "95.32"},
      {"id": 86, "Period": "22-Aug-22-18-Sep-22", "value": "95.52"},
      {"id": 87, "Period": "01-Sep-22-25-Sep-22", "value": "96.05"},
      {"id": 88, "Period": "05-Sep-22-30-Sep-22", "value": "95.78"},
      {"id": 89, "Period": "12-Sep-22-09-Oct-22", "value": "95.57"},
      {"id": 90, "Period": "19-Sep-22-16-Oct-22", "value": "94.76"},
      {"id": 91, "Period": "26-Sep-22-23-Oct-22", "value": "93.88"},
      {"id": 92, "Period": "01-Oct-22-31-Oct-22", "value": "94.58"},
      {"id": 93, "Period": "10-Oct-22-06-Nov-22", "value": "94.38"},
      {"id": 94, "Period": "17-Oct-22-13-Nov-22", "value": "94.89"},
      {"id": 95, "Period": "24-Oct-22-20-Nov-22", "value": "96.01"},
      {"id": 96, "Period": "01-Nov-22-30-Nov-22", "value": "96.2"},
      {"id": 97, "Period": "07-Nov-22-04-Dec-22", "value": "96.47"},
      {"id": 98, "Period": "14-Nov-22-11-Dec-22", "value": "96.83"},
      {"id": 99, "Period": "21-Nov-22-18-Dec-22", "value": "96.03"},
      {"id": 100, "Period": "01-Dec-22-25-Dec-22", "value": "95.7"},
      {"id": 101, "Period": "05-Dec-22-31-Dec-22", "value": "95.66"},
      {"id": 102, "Period": "12-Dec-22-08-Jan-23", "value": "95.71"},
      {"id": 103, "Period": "19-Dec-22-15-Jan-23", "value": "95.53"},
      {"id": 104, "Period": "26-Dec-22-22-Jan-23", "value": "95.42"},
      {"id": 105, "Period": "01-Jan-23-31-Jan-23", "value": "95.32"},
      {"id": 106, "Period": "09-Jan-23-05-Feb-23", "value": "95.0"},
      {"id": 107, "Period": "16-Jan-23-12-Feb-23", "value": "96.07"},
      {"id": 108, "Period": "23-Jan-23-19-Feb-23", "value": "96.11"},
      {"id": 109, "Period": "01-Feb-23-28-Feb-23", "value": "96.2"},
      {"id": 110, "Period": "06-Feb-23-05-Mar-23", "value": "95.95"},
      {"id": 111, "Period": "13-Feb-23-12-Mar-23", "value": "95.04"},
      {"id": 112, "Period": "20-Feb-23-19-Mar-23", "value": "95.01"},
      {"id": 113, "Period": "01-Mar-23-26-Mar-23", "value": "94.54"},
      {"id": 114, "Period": "06-Mar-23-31-Mar-23", "value": "95.21"},
      {"id": 115, "Period": "13-Mar-23-09-Apr-23", "value": "95.8"},
      {"id": 116, "Period": "20-Mar-23-16-Apr-23", "value": "95.53"},
      {"id": 117, "Period": "27-Mar-23-23-Apr-23", "value": "95.93"},
      {"id": 118, "Period": "01-Apr-23-30-Apr-23", "value": "95.72"},
      {"id": 119, "Period": "10-Apr-23-07-May-23", "value": "96.03"},
      {"id": 120, "Period": "17-Apr-23-14-May-23", "value": "96.4"},
      {"id": 121, "Period": "24-Apr-23-21-May-23", "value": "95.69"},
      {"id": 122, "Period": "01-May-23-31-May-23", "value": "95.26"},
      {"id": 123, "Period": "08-May-23-04-Jun-23", "value": "94.94"},
      {"id": 124, "Period": "15-May-23-11-Jun-23", "value": "94.64"},
      {"id": 125, "Period": "22-May-23-18-Jun-23", "value": "95.31"},
      {"id": 126, "Period": "01-Jun-23-25-Jun-23", "value": "95.7"},
      {"id": 127, "Period": "05-Jun-23-30-Jun-23", "value": "95.49"},
      {"id": 128, "Period": "12-Jun-23-09-Jul-23", "value": "95.06"},
      {"id": 129, "Period": "19-Jun-23-16-Jul-23", "value": "93.93"},
      {"id": 130, "Period": "26-Jun-23-23-Jul-23", "value": "93.15"},
      {"id": 131, "Period": "01-Jul-23-31-Jul-23", "value": "92.83"},
      {"id": 132, "Period": "10-Jul-23-06-Aug-23", "value": "93.13"},
      {"id": 133, "Period": "17-Jul-23-13-Aug-23", "value": "93.76"},
      {"id": 134, "Period": "24-Jul-23-20-Aug-23", "value": "94.16"},
      {"id": 135, "Period": "01-Aug-23-27-Aug-23", "value": "94.67"},
      {"id": 136, "Period": "07-Aug-23-31-Aug-23", "value": "94.41"},
      {"id": 137, "Period": "14-Aug-23-10-Sep-23", "value": "94.54"},
      {"id": 138, "Period": "21-Aug-23-17-Sep-23", "value": "94.03"},
      {"id": 139, "Period": "28-Aug-23-24-Sep-23", "value": "93.6"},
      {"id": 140, "Period": "01-Sep-23-30-Sep-23", "value": "93.87"},
      {"id": 141, "Period": "11-Sep-23-08-Oct-23", "value": "93.51"},
      {"id": 142, "Period": "18-Sep-23-15-Oct-23", "value": "94.3"},
      {"id": 143, "Period": "25-Sep-23-22-Oct-23", "value": "94.41"},
      {"id": 144, "Period": "01-Oct-23-31-Oct-23", "value": "94.29"},
      {"id": 145, "Period": "09-Oct-23-05-Nov-23", "value": "94.73"},
      {"id": 146, "Period": "16-Oct-23-12-Nov-23", "value": "94.8"},
      {"id": 147, "Period": "23-Oct-23-19-Nov-23", "value": "95.3"},
      {"id": 148, "Period": "01-Nov-23-26-Nov-23", "value": "95.41"},
      {"id": 149, "Period": "06-Nov-23-30-Nov-23", "value": "95.53"},
      {"id": 150, "Period": "13-Nov-23-10-Dec-23", "value": "94.71"},
      {"id": 151, "Period": "20-Nov-23-17-Dec-23", "value": "94.62"},
      {"id": 152, "Period": "27-Nov-23-24-Dec-23", "value": "94.52"},
      {"id": 153, "Period": "01-Dec-23-31-Dec-23", "value": "94.48"},
      {"id": 154, "Period": "11-Dec-23-07-Jan-24", "value": "95.02"},
      {"id": 155, "Period": "18-Dec-23-14-Jan-24", "value": "94.43"},
      {"id": 156, "Period": "25-Dec-23-21-Jan-24", "value": "94.0"},
      {"id": 157, "Period": "01-Jan-24-31-Jan-24", "value": "93.78"},
      {"id": 158, "Period": "08-Jan-24-04-Feb-24", "value": "93.38"},
      {"id": 159, "Period": "15-Jan-24-11-Feb-24", "value": "93.55"},
      {"id": 160, "Period": "22-Jan-24-18-Feb-24", "value": "93.99"},
      {"id": 161, "Period": "01-Feb-24-25-Feb-24", "value": "94.01"},
      {"id": 162, "Period": "05-Feb-24-29-Feb-24", "value": "94.83"},
      {"id": 163, "Period": "12-Feb-24-10-Mar-24", "value": "95.11"},
      {"id": 164, "Period": "19-Feb-24-17-Mar-24", "value": "94.12"},
      {"id": 165, "Period": "26-Feb-24-24-Mar-24", "value": "94.0"},
      {"id": 166, "Period": "01-Mar-24-31-Mar-24", "value": "93.4"},
      {"id": 167, "Period": "11-Mar-24-07-Apr-24", "value": "92.7"},
      {"id": 168, "Period": "18-Mar-24-14-Apr-24", "value": "93.0"},
      {"id": 169, "Period": "25-Mar-24-21-Apr-24", "value": "92.69"},
      {"id": 170, "Period": "01-Apr-24-30-Apr-24", "value": "92.96"},
      {"id": 171, "Period": "08-Apr-24-05-May-24", "value": "93.47"},
      {"id": 172, "Period": "15-Apr-24-12-May-24", "value": "93.92"},
      {"id": 173, "Period": "22-Apr-24-19-May-24", "value": "94.19"},
      {"id": 174, "Period": "01-May-24-26-May-24", "value": "94.75"},
      {"id": 175, "Period": "06-May-24-31-May-24", "value": "94.04"},
      {"id": 176, "Period": "13-May-24-09-Jun-24", "value": "93.51"},
      {"id": 177, "Period": "20-May-24-16-Jun-24", "value": "92.91"},
      {"id": 178, "Period": "27-May-24-23-Jun-24", "value": "92.13"},
      {"id": 179, "Period": "01-Jun-24-30-Jun-24", "value": "92.62"},
      {"id": 180, "Period": "10-Jun-24-07-Jul-24", "value": "92.36"},
      {"id": 181, "Period": "17-Jun-24-14-Jul-24", "value": "92.39"},
      {"id": 182, "Period": "24-Jun-24-21-Jul-24", "value": "92.22"},
      {"id": 183, "Period": "01-Jul-24-31-Jul-24", "value": "91.57"}
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "width": "700",
      "height": 250,
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "point": {"display": true, "shape": "triangle-up", "size": 100},
            "cursor": "pointer",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "id",
              "title": "Period(4 week)",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "sort": {"field": "id"}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "value",
              "title": "VALUE",
              "sort": null,
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {"labelExpr": "datum.value+'%'"},
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {"datum": "VALUE"},
            "tooltip": [
              {"field": "Period", "title": "Period", "type": "ordinal"},
              {"field": "value", "title": "TDIR", "type": "quantitative"},
               {"field": "id", "title": "Id", "type": "quantitative"}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line"},
          "transform": [
            {"regression": "value", "on": "id", "params": false, "order": 2}
          ],
          "encoding": {
            "y": {
              "field": "value",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {"position": "left"},
              "sort": null
            },
            "x": {
              "field": "id",
              "title": "Period(4 week)",
             "type": "ordinal",
              "sort": {"field": "id"}
            },
            "color": {
              "datum": "Linear-Regression (VALUE)",
              "scale": {"range": ["#444436"]},
              "legend": {"orient": "bottom"}
            }
          },
          "resolve": {
            "scale": {
              "color": "independent",
              "shape": "independent",
              "legend": "independent"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent", "shape": "independent"}}
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "columns": 3,
      "orient": "bottom",
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}
    }
  }
}


how i show label according to field 'Period'  i used id on x field because on Period it is not showing trend line
